# How to convert a raster file to .asc without losing spatial reference in ArcMap10.5

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

I am trying to convert several raster files (some with continuous and some with categorical data) into .asc files.

I have used the "Raster to ASCII" tool, but when I click on properties of the newly created file the spatial reference is lost. 
I tried to "define projection" and to add a spatial reference in ArcCatalog, but so far nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ASCII files don't have a spatial reference property. Save the WKT string in a parallel file.

Comment: Open up an ascii file in text pad, where does it say what spatial reference it is, the answer it does not! As @Vince says that information is not part of the ascii format. Look at the help file at the page "Esri ASCII raster format".

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes so much more sense now :D

Answer (score 1):

I use 10.6 and export as *.txt file. When I go to the file with explorer, I have a prj-file with the same name which contains the projection-information. My ArcMap also recognizes the *.txt as raster with projection. I am not sure if that is new in 10.6